# Redirect to new page after video is paused for more than 1 minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I am building a custom video player using video.js and I am trying to create an idle time function that redirect the video to home page after being more than 1 minute on pause. What is the easiest way to do this?

```js
myPlayer.on("pause", function() {
  window.location = "../index.html";
});
```

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were most of the way there, you just needed to use `setTimeout()`, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for more information. You'll want to make sure you cancel the timer once play is clicked again.

**Code**

```
//Global timer object, needed so we can clear it
var timer = null;

myPlayer.on("pause", function() 
{
  //Set the time once the player is paused. Note: 60000 is 1 minute
  timer = setTimeout(function(){window.location = "../index.html"}, 60000);
});

myPlayer.on("play", function() 
{
  //If the user clicks play stop the timer
  //You may need to use this code in other events
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```